# Magento 2 Catalog Image upload save Cloudflare blocks request technical problem with the server created an error

Tags: magento2

Saving a uploading and saving catalog image to a catalog as an admin has an error with the message.

[image]
A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

Answer (score 0):

View the Cloudflare for the site and look at the Firewall Event Log.

Enter the Cloudflare Ray ID from the response body from the Magento admin panel when you click save you can view this in the browsers network tab under developer tools.

Example:
Cloudflare Ray ID: **2a3fe4123f456fa**

Search and click on Details
View the Rule(s) Triggered on the Block action.

[image]

For me it was Cloudflare Specials.

View the Firewall | Managed Rules in the Cloudflare Dashboard

Scroll down to Cloudflare Specials.
Turn it off.

[image]

Attempt uploading a category image and saving.

It works now success.